# Angular - Unable to print information from API

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I changed my API REST and when I swap, it doesn't print the information.

My API send me this JSON structure :

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Id": "#AJUST",
      "Nom": "TRONY",
      "Prenom": "JACOB",
    }
  ]
}
```

I make this request with Angular :

```js
getEmployee(){
  return this.http.get<any>(this.localUrlAPI+"/salarie/GetAllEmployee")
    .pipe(map((res:any)=>{
      return res;
    }))
}

getAllEmployee(){
  this.api.getEmployee()
    .subscribe(res=>{
      this.EmployeeData = res;
    })
}
```

Why did that print me nothing in my application?
Thx for the time that you take to help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is `EmployeeData` data type?

Comment: Thank you! EmployeeData type is : EmployeeData !: any;

Comment: I think the error come from the fact that when i make the get, the response is Data and not id, nom, and prenom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get the array in `Data`, with `map` rxjs operator to get `res.Data` instead of `res`.

```js
map((res: any) => {
    return res.Data;
})
```

```js
getEmployee() {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.localUrlAPI+"/salarie/GetAllEmployee").pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      return res.Data;
    })
  );
}
```

And would suggest specifying `EmployeeData` as **array** type rather than `any`.

```js
EmployeeData!: any[];
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qpykn4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! Have a nice day